# React Native Expo SDK upgrade to 36

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sdk, expo

I am working on my React Native app built with expo. Today I was really bothered by the console that all the time was reminding me that there is a new version of expo, so I decided to update it. I followed the steps given on the expo docs. Everything in update seemed working fine but in nearly a half command :
expo upgrade stacked and returned me this error [expo NPM ERR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05y7P.png)
I listed previous solutions that I should check my package.json file and app.json file to match the sdk versions but I got all three set up on the same :

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "bakalarka",
    "slug": "bakalarka",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "36.0.0", ...
```

and my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "expo": "^36.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~8.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.0.0",
    "linear-gradient": "^1.0.6",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz", ...
```

When I just want to start the app my Android emulator shows me error as: React native version mismatch.
 Does anyone know where might be the problem?
 Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 8):

Execute `expo update` from your project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the expected result of doing so? How will they know if it solved the problem. If it doesn't solve the problem what side effects could it have? Next time please format suggested commands with the backtick character.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your last line with:

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz",
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following?

1. deleting your node_modules
2. `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

use it
ncu -u
to your cmd, it will update your expo SDK